# Should one use distances (dissimilarities) or similarities in R for clustering?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm doing a cluster problem, and the   `proxy`   package in R provides both dist and simil functions.

For my purpose I need a distance matrix, so I initially used dist, and here's the code:

```
distanceMatrix <- dist(dfm[,-1], method='Pearson')
clusters <- hclust(distanceMatrix)  
clusters$labels <- dfm[,1]#colnames(dfm)[-1]
plot(clusters, labels=clusters$labels)
```

But after I ploted the image I found that the cluster result is not the way I expecte it to be, since I know what it should look like.

So I tried simil instead, and the code is like:

```
distanceMatrix <- simil(dfm[,-1], method='Pearson')
clusters <- hclust(pr_simil2dist(distanceMatrix))   
clusters$labels <- dfm[,1]#colnames(dfm)[-1]
plot(clusters, labels=clusters$labels)
```

This code computes a similarity matrix using simil, then convert it to distance matrix using pr_simil2dist, then I plot it and get the result I expected !

I'm confused about the relationship between dist and simil. According to the relationship described in the documentation, shouldn't the two code snippet has the same result?

Where am I wrong ?

Edit:

You can try my code with dfm of the following value, sorry for the bad indentation.

```
                             Blog china kids music yahoo want wrong
                         Gawker     0    1     0     0    7     0
                  Read/WriteWeb     2    0     1     3    1     1
                 WWdN: In Exile     0    2     4     0    0     0
           ProBlogger Blog Tips     0    0     0     0    2     0
                    Seth's Blog     0    0     1     0    3     1
 The Huffington Post | Raw Feed     0    6     0     0   14     5
```

Edit:

Actually the sample data is taken from a very big data frame using `tail`, and I get completely different matrix using dist and simil+pr_simil2dist. The full data can found [here.](http://kiwitobes.com/clusters/blogdata.txt)

In case I made other silly mistakes, here's the full code of my function:

The code I use to read in data:

```
dfm<- read.table(filename, header=T, sep='\t', quote='')
```

Code for clustering:

```
hcluster <- function(dfm, distance='Pearson'){
    dfm <- tail(dfm)[,c(1:7)] # I use this to give the sample data.
    distanceMatrix <- simil(dfm[,-1], method=pearson)
    clusters <- hclust(pr_simil2dist(distanceMatrix))   
    clusters$labels <- dfm[,1]#colnames(dfm)[-1]
    plot(clusters, labels=clusters$labels)
}
```

Matrix using dist:

```
           94         95         96         97         98
95 -0.2531580                                            
96 -0.2556859 -0.4629100                                 
97  0.9897783 -0.1581139 -0.2927700                      
98  0.8742800 -0.2760788 -0.1022397  0.9079594           
99  0.9114339 -0.5020405 -0.2810414  0.8713293  0.8096980
```

Matrix using simil+pr_simil2dist:

```
           94         95         96         97         98
95 1.25315802                                            
96 1.25568595 1.46291005                                 
97 0.01022173 1.15811388 1.29277002                      
98 0.12572004 1.27607882 1.10223973 0.09204062           
99 0.08856608 1.50204055 1.28104139 0.12867065 0.19030202
```

You can see that corresponding elements in the two matrices add up to 1, which I think is not right. So there must be something I'm doing wrong.

Edit:

After I specify names in the read.table function to read in the data frame, the dist way and simil+pr_simil2dist way give the same correct result. **So technically problem solved**, but I don't know why my original way of handling data frame have anything to do with dist and simil.

Any one has a clue on that ?

Comment: Your code isn't exactly reproducible. Care to give a simple example that we can run on our machines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by not as per expected. If I compute the distance/similarity matrix via `proxy::dist()` or via `simil()` and convert to a dissimilarity I get the same matrix:

```
> dist(dfm, method='Pearson')
                                  Gawker Read/WriteWeb WWdN: In Exile ProBlogger Blog Tips Seth's Blog
Read/WriteWeb                  0.2662006                                                              
WWdN: In Exile                 0.2822594     0.2662006                                                
ProBlogger Blog Tips           0.2928932     0.5917517      0.6984887                                 
Seth's Blog                    0.2662006     0.2928932      0.4072510            0.2928932            
The Huffington Post | Raw Feed 0.1835034     0.2312939      0.2662006            0.2928932   0.2312939

> pr_simil2dist(simil(dfm, method = "pearson"))
                                  Gawker Read/WriteWeb WWdN: In Exile ProBlogger Blog Tips Seth's Blog
Read/WriteWeb                  0.2662006                                                              
WWdN: In Exile                 0.2822594     0.2662006                                                
ProBlogger Blog Tips           0.2928932     0.5917517      0.6984887                                 
Seth's Blog                    0.2662006     0.2928932      0.4072510            0.2928932            
The Huffington Post | Raw Feed 0.1835034     0.2312939      0.2662006            0.2928932   0.2312939
```

and

```
d1 <- dist(dfm, method='Pearson')
d2 <- pr_simil2dist(simil(dfm, method = "pearson"))
h1 <- hclust(d1)
h2 <- hclust(d2)
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2))
plot(h1)
plot(h2)
layout(1)
all.equal(h1, h2)
```

The last line yields:

```
> all.equal(h1, h2)
[1] "Component 6: target, current do not match when deparsed"
```

which is telling us that `h1` and `h2` are exactly the same except for the matched function call (obviously as we used `d1` and `d2` in the respective calls).

The figure produced is:

[image]

If you set your object up correctly, then you won't need to fiddle with the labels. Look at the `row.names` argument to `read.table()` to see how to specify a column be used as the row labels when the data are read in.

All of this was done using:

```
dfm <- structure(list(china = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), kids = c(1L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 6L), music = c(0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L), yahoo = c(0L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), want = c(7L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 14L), wrong = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L)), .Names = c("china", "kids", "music", "yahoo", 
"want", "wrong"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gawker", 
"Read/WriteWeb", "WWdN: In Exile", "ProBlogger Blog Tips", "Seth's Blog", 
"The Huffington Post | Raw Feed"))
```

Comment: This is odd ... I get completely different matrix using dist and simil+pr_simil2dist. See my edited post please.

Comment: I tried your code on my machine and they DID give the same result, so I still have no idea what's the problem is ...

Comment: Problem solved after I specify names in the read.table function to read in the data frame. But I don't know why my original way of handling data frame have anything to do with dist and simil.